# creating toggling with JSON

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have this particular JSON with two keys ("cars","others"). How can I create toggling in my website using HTML/CSS/JavaScript such that

- if I click on "cars" it displays the car.items (small vehicle, large vehicle). The texts should be of color:red.
- if I click on "others" it should hide the car.items and display others.items in blue color.

Note: The toggle can be a button or a link that's fine as long as it is toggling properly.

```json
    {
    "cars": {
    "items": ["small-vehicle","large-vehicle"],
    "color": "red"
    },

    "others": {
    "items": ["swimming pool","plane","ship",],
    "color": "blue"
     }
    }
```

Comment: See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO! Do you have some code you could insert to show what your actual issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code which will get you started.

It will alert() display the color of each when you click the appropriate button.

Now, it'll be up to you to work this out properly to get it working the way you want it to.

I updated with a select list so you can try it that way too.  Run the code and check it out.

```js
let items = {
"cars": {
"items": ["small-vehicle","large-vehicle"],
"color": "red"
},

"others": {
"items": ["swimming pool","plane","ship",],
"color": "blue"
 }
}

function showMeCarColor(){
  alert(items.cars.color);
}

function showMeOtherColor(){
  alert(items.others.color);
}

function doThing(){
  let selectedItem = document.querySelector("#itemList").value;
  switch (selectedItem){
    case "car":{
      alert(`car is : ${items.cars.color}`);
      break;
    }
    case "other":{
       alert(`other is : ${items.others.color}`);
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showMeCarColor()">Cars</button>
<button onclick="showMeOtherColor()">Other</button>

<select id="itemList" onInput="doThing()">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="car">Car</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: Here I don’t want to display “red” or “blue” , I want to display car.items that is “small vehicle” and “large vehicle” on the webpage and color of the texts should be red in color and the same for others.items